# C# - Como fechar o form de login(form inicial do programa) após chamar outro form?

Tags: c#, winforms

Eu consegui fazer toda a parte de banco de dados do formulário de login, de modo que se o usuário digite login/senha com dados que estejam no banco de dados, ele consiga acessar.

Só que quando abro o outro form, o de login não fecha e o máximo que consegui foi escondê-lo com o this.visible = false;

Eu quero que o segundo form abra e o de login feche sem que a aplicação toda pare de funcionar, já que com o this.close()/close() tudo fechava!

Meu código do botão de login está assim:

obs: "acessar" é variável booleana que eu atribui quando tava criando a parte de acesso com login/senha do banco de dados do programa.

```
if (acessar == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Logado com sucesso!");
            this.Visible = false;

            Form2 novaform = new Form2();
            novaform.ShowDialog();

        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Erro ao logar");          
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Dá uma olhada nesse post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5548746/c-sharp-open-a-new-form-then-close-the-current-form

Basicamente é fazer o seguinte quando for mostrar o seu Form2:

```
this.Hide();
var form2 = new Form2();
form2.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close(); 
form2.Show();
```

O primeiro form fica "escondido" até que o segundo seja fechado, disparando o evento Closed que irá de fato fechar o primeiro.

Answer (score 0):

Eu fiz algo mais ou menos assim no meu programa.

```
//dentro da classe base do programa
public static bool reconect = true;
public static Usuario usuario = null;

//metodo Main()
while(reconect)
{
    reconect = false;
    Application.Run(new Login());
    // a variavel usuario é do tipo static, e é modificada quando o login é efetuado;
    if (usuario != null)
    {
        //caso seja feito o logoff, o usuario é setado em null e reconect para true.
        //se a TelaPrincipal ou Login for fechada ela automaticamente quebra o loop
        Application.Run(new TelaPrincipal());
    }
}
```